# jQuery - what does $$('#bla') mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

lately I saw jQuery-code

`$$('#bla')`

I ask myselft, what does this two `$` mean? I made a quick search, but I can't find anything, that explains it. Can someone maybe explain it to me?

Comment: The global `jQuery` object may be represented by any valid symbol, `$` is just the default. The code you're looking at may just have something like `jQuery(function($$) { /* $$ is now jQuery */ });`. It's impossible to tell without knowing more about the code in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$$` has no meaning in jQuery at all. Of course, if someone does `var $$ = jQuery;` (or more likely, `var $$ = jQuery.noConflict();`), then it will refer to the jQuery function.

You may have been looking at [MooTools](http://mootools.net) code, or [PrototypeJS](http://prototypejs.org) code, or [Chrome console code](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/command-line/command-line-reference?hl=en#selector-1). In all three of those, `$$` searches for all elements that match the given CSS selector (rather like jQuery's `$`).

Comment: Also, it can be a function name :)

Comment: @HappyCoding: Indeed, it could be just about anything. The point is that it's not a built-in jQuery thing. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Bad example but it's better understanding for your question:

```
var $$ = function (bla) {
    console.log(bla)
};

$$('#bla'); // #bla
```